# In wordpress how can I scrape and show social media data of users like in upfluence.com and shoutcart.com?

Tags: wordpress, web-scraping, wordpress-theming, social-networking, custom-wordpress-pages

In wordpress how can I scrape and show social media data of users like in upfluence.com and shoutcart.com?
I need to show instagram followers and youtube subscriber counts and other data in each users profile.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried

Comment: Did you ever work this out? I need to do something very similar.